# Get line number of object key definition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, config

Say I have a file like so:

```
export const dotReadme = {
  config1: { // <-- I want to get this line number.
    brief: 'foo1234',
    title: 'foo!',
  },
  config2: { // <-- And I want to get this line number.
    ...
  },
}
```

I want to provide traceability as to where each config key was defined.

So at a later point I want to print something like:

```
`config1` was defined at `config.js:1`
`config2` was defined at `config.js:6`
```

What is the best way to do this? Does something exist already?

### Current thoughts

- A babel plugin which will nest a key called `__line`. However, this only works when the value is an object. I could box all primitive types as objects to make this work I guess.
- Parse the AST using babylon or something and search for the line numbers of the keys.

Maybe some instrumentation libraries would be useful as it seems like a similar thing, maybe `babel-plugin-istanbul`.

### Constraints

It should provide the line numbers back to the original source via the sourcemaps.

Users will be creating, compiling, editing, and potentially publishing these config files to npm.

---

### Update

So it looks like you can box primitives in JS, you just have to use `new String`, which will then allow you to add additional properties.

```
> const str = new String('foo')
undefined
> str.__line = 1
1
> str
{ [String: 'foo'] __line: 1 }
>
```

I put together a proof of concept babel plugin [here](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/83224c2302cbc3b15a50402a1df75601/2a32c017dbe1365c1e2ea27434d65c80582ecef8). At the moment this feels like the best approach.

Only downside is requiring the user to compile their config files with this babel plugin. But I guess this is only for additional fine-grained debugging, and the boxing should not affect any code.

Comment: Sounds like ctags to me

Comment: I don't see why there are votes-to-close. I think the question is pretty clear, and applicable to many config tools in JS.